# fix score range to [-1,1] in sklearn GradientBoostingClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

When using GradientBoostingClassifier in sklearn I get scores from the decision_function larger than between [-1,1]. Is it possible to force the classifier to calculate only scores between [-1,1]?

The problem is, that I need to convert the classification into an xml file which will be used inside tmva and tmva can only handle scores in that range so it is not enough to just scale my scores to that range.

Comment: Why not channel it through an `arctan` in both training and predicting?

Comment: @Willem arctan is not bounded by [-1,1], you probably meant hiperbolic tangent (tanh)?

Comment: Yeah indeed. Or any kind of transformation with an (0,1) domain.